# How to force hard reload on Firefox for Android

Tags: html, css, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

How is it possible to force a hard reload on Firefox for Android?

On desktop it works with Ctrl + F5, but how does it work in the app?

Comment: not sure if this is in the right place but base on Mozilla: To reload a page tap the 3 dot menu in the upper right and then in the menu that appears press the reload button. You can force a completely clean load of the page by long pressing on the reload button.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Open the menu (3 dots in the status bar) and press the reload button for a few seconds to force a hard page reload.

Comment: This doesn't work me on firefox for android

Comment: That is definitely how it used to work, but ever since Mozilla's 'simplification' of their android app, it is just a normal reload for me.

Comment: It just did the trick for me after going crazy for a while trying to figure out why the new CSS style wasn't being picked up. Firefox 115.2.1 for Android.

Answer (score 1):

Usually i'm toggling between desktop/mobile view. It's the most convenient way for me.

Comment: Desktop view is under the 3-dots kebab menu, so it is actually not that simpler than the other answer, but it worked for me, and I am now not able to test the other answer.